# MySQL group_concat returning values (including NULL) from two tables

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I have two tables. I'm trying to return the thumbnail_img and fullsize_img column respective values for each article_steps row. I want this to include NULL if there are no matching values for each step, too.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article_steps` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `step_num` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `step_title` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `step_body` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `step_body` (`step_body`,`step_title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article_steps_gallery` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `step_num` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail_img` text NOT NULL,
  `fullsize_img` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

Here's my statement:

```
SELECT a.id,a.step_num, a.step_title,a.step_body, CONCAT( (case when a.step_num=s.step_num then GROUP_CONCAT(fullsize_img, '|',thumbnail_img SEPARATOR '    ') end) ) AS images
FROM article_steps a, article_steps_gallery s 
WHERE a.article_id=s.article_id 
AND a.article_id=2
GROUP BY step_num
```

This is returning:

```
id  step_num    step_title  step_body   images  
5   1           faketitle1  fakebody1   NULL
6   2           faketitle2  fakebody2   image.jpg|image_thumbnail.jpg
7   3           faketitle3  fakebody3   NULL
8   4           faketitle4  fakebody4   NULL
```

The only step_num which should be returning NULL is #1 --- however it's only correctly returning fullsize_img & thumbnail_img for step_num 2.

---

```
SELECT a.step_num, a.step_title,a.step_body, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fullsize_img) AS image, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT thumbnail_img) AS thumbnail
FROM article_steps a, article_steps_gallery s 
WHERE a.article_id=s.article_id 
AND a.step_num=s.step_num 
AND a.article_id=2
GROUP BY step_num
```

This statement here returns the correct images. But, being that it's GROUP_CONCAT it doesn't return NULL values. So the step_num 1, which doesn't have any images doesn't get returned.

```
id  step_num    step_title  step_body   image       thumbnail
6   2           faketitle2  fakebody2   image2.jpg  image2_thumbnail.jpg
7   3           faketitle3  fakebody3   image3.jpg  image3_thumbnail.jpg
8   4           faketitle4  fakebody4   image4.jpg  image4_thumbnail.jpg
```

Comment: Modify the concat to this to see if your data is setup as you think it is:  `CONCAT( (case when a.step_num=s.step_num then GROUP_CONCAT(coalesce(fullsize_img,'Nope'), '|',coalesce(thumbnail_img, 'Nope') SEPARATOR '    ') end) )`

Comment: why are you concating a | along with a separator of a bunch of spaces?? this looks like a really bad idea

Comment: xQbert - your CONCAT statement returns the exact same output

Comment: John, you're right. I suppose I could just create separate CONCAT clauses for the fullsize_img and thumbnail_img.

Comment: You wouldn't be getting IDs 5,6,8 if there were not records in article_steps_gallery for those IDs as the a.article_ID = s.article_Id would eliminate them. if you add s.fullsize_Image and s.thumbnail_img to your output what does it look like?  Do steps 1,2,4 all have values in those 2 fields... OH DANG IT... BURNED BY MYSQL GROUP BY extensions AGAIN!  (Answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with the following code:

```
SELECT a.id,a.step_num, a.step_title,a.step_body,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fullsize_img) FROM article_steps_gallery s  WHERE a.step_num=s.step_num AND a.article_id=s.article_id) AS image,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(thumbnail_img) FROM article_steps_gallery s  WHERE a.step_num=s.step_num AND a.article_id=s.article_id) AS thumbnail
FROM article_steps a
WHERE a.article_id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a group by, you're not doing any aggregates?

```
SELECT a.id,a.step_num, a.step_title,a.step_body, CONCAT( (case when a.step_num=s.step_num then GROUP_CONCAT(fullsize_img, '|',thumbnail_img SEPARATOR '    ') end) ) AS images
FROM article_steps a, article_steps_gallery s 
WHERE a.article_id=s.article_id 
AND a.article_id=2
```

PER DOCS on mySQL Group by: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

The server is ***free to choose*** any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

So the reason you're getting NULL is that one of the records that is being rolled up due to your group by is null and the RDBMS is choosing that one at random.

if you MUST have a group by to eliminate duplicates...  (why are there duplicates?)

Then either use distinct or group by every field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.step_num, a.step_title,a.step_body, CONCAT( (case when a.step_num=s.step_num then GROUP_CONCAT(fullsize_img, '|',thumbnail_img SEPARATOR '    ') end) ) AS images
    FROM article_steps a, article_steps_gallery s 
    WHERE a.article_id=s.article_id 
    AND a.article_id=2
```

.

```
SELECT a.id,a.step_num, a.step_title,a.step_body, CONCAT( (case when a.step_num=s.step_num then GROUP_CONCAT(fullsize_img, '|',thumbnail_img SEPARATOR '    ') end) ) AS images
FROM article_steps a, article_steps_gallery s 
WHERE a.article_id=s.article_id 
AND a.article_id=2
GROUP BY a.id,a.step_num, a.step_title,a.step_body, CONCAT( (case when a.step_num=s.step_num then GROUP_CONCAT(fullsize_img, '|',thumbnail_img SEPARATOR '    ') end) )
```

Comment: This is correctly returning the value for the images. Article 1, step 1 returns the matching images. Article 2, step 1 returns NULL. This is correct. However, it's only returning the first row and not all of the matching rows. If this could return all of the rows, it'd be golden.

Comment: xQbert, thank you for your help. I wasn't aware of my incorrect usage of GROUP BY either. I'll use it correctly in the future.

Comment: Remove the group by or distinct, it would return all the rows